# How to move from one view controller to another view controller though dynamic collection view using swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

[screenshot of image slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TJJz.png)

I have a dynamic collection view. How to move from one view controller to another by clicking the cell of the collection view?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

there is a delegate method of collectionview named `didselect` you can use it

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// write code to go from one viewcontroller to another
}
```

Comment: add the given method below your collectionview's delegates (code of collection view)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given collectionView to delegate. See below how to set delegate.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionvVew.delegate = self
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Write your navigation controller name instead of **ViewController**
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

I have shared my answer. Let me know if I am wrong in understanding your question.

Comment: Thank you sir for your feedback but this code does not work. It doesn't change the view controller any more.

Comment: @Abhi If you can share your controller code for a better understanding?

Comment: can you kindly share your email id so that I can send total code used in controller otherwise its too long

Answer (score 0):

Try to add gesture recognizer (in your cellForItemAt func) to cell contentView and call your destination controller programmatically:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "yourCellId", for: indexPath) as! yourCell
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeVc))
        cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    return cell
}
```

or you can add gesture to the imageView cell like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! yourCollecctionViewCell
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeVc))
    cell.yourImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // don't forget to enable user interaction in your image view
    cell.yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

 return cell
}
```

now write the function to change VC:

```
@objc fileprivate func changeVc() {
    let vc = YourDestinationController()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen // if you don't want full screen comment this line, 
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this in case of navigation controller:

```
@objc fileprivate func changeVc() {
    let vc = YourdestinationController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```